# Trying to combine a carousel jquery plugin with an RSS parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I've got some digital signs with limited dimensions, so I need to be able to have variable-height, non-static content slowly crawl up the screen. I'm using a two separate plugins to handle content scrolling and content parsing. Originally both functions I used were written as anonymous functions, but I converted them to methods of an object so I could later add some additional functionality.

I've tested both methods independently and they work. However, combining the two results in the final content not scrolling as intended. I have a few fiddles created with demo code:

1. [functioning scrollfeed() method, using filler text](http://jsfiddle.net/brendensparks/BHSLr/)
2. [non-functioning combo of getfeed() and scrollfeed()](http://jsfiddle.net/brendensparks/rs3WL/3/)

(Version 6 of the second fiddle verifies that the getfeed() method does work by itself)

I've also tested with 3 separate RSS feeds that have very different content structures and the getfeed() method worked in each instance.

If anyone can provide any insight, I would be very appreciative. My JavaScript skills are limited.

```
var remoteFeedManager = {
    getfeed: function () {
        $('#feed').feeds({
            feeds: {
                calendar: 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_tech.rss'
            },
            entryTemplate: '<div class="feed-entry">' +
                '<h4 class="feed-entry-title"><!=title!></h4>' +
            //'<div class="feed-entry-date"><!=publishedDate!></div>' +
            '<p class="feed-entry-content"><!=content!></p>' +
                '</div>',
            preprocess: function (feed) {
                // Inside the callback 'this' corresponds to the entry being processed
                // Remove CDATA tags from feed
                this.content.replace("<![CDATA[", "");
                this.content.replace("]]>", "");
            }
        });

    },
    scrollfeed: function () {
        $(".verticalscroller").carouFredSel({
            direction: "up",
            align: "top",
            width: 517,
            height: 100,
            auto: {
                easing: "linear",
                timeoutDuration: 0,
                duration: 10000
            }
        });
    }
};
remoteFeedManager.getfeed();
remoteFeedManager.scrollfeed();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the getfeed operation is an asynchronous operation that hasn't finished loading the RSS feed by the time you call scrollfeed.  I'm not sure what plug-in you're using, but see if there is some sort of event that calls a defined function when the RSS feed is done loading.  If so, you can set it such that it calls the scrollfeed function.